# TeXstudio - get output of pgf externalize in log Window

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, texstudio, tikz-external

I like the functionality of TeXstudio to show me errors concerning my latex-code in the Log-window.
If I use `pgfplots` and `externalize` all externalized pictures are compiled in a separate call. So I just get notified "There were error(s) during compilation" or something similar but I do not receive a list of what is wrong with my document. Since the log is created (it is in the Tikz-externalize folder) I was wondering if it is possible to feed this log to TeXstudio somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Your request would need two operations that are not supported by TXS.

1) Doing something user-defined on failures of calls to external programs.
2) Displaying user-defined content in the log window.

As a crude workaround, you could open the log in an editor tab and (manually) switch there if there are errors. You could also write a macro for that and assign a shortcut.

```
%SCRIPT
app.load("/path/to/tikz_externalize/log")
```

This is probably as good as you can get.